# Android Layout Position of Elements

Tags: android, android-layout, android-layout-weight

How to give the elements in the layout a constant position that will not changed if i changes the language? I wrote this layout but unfortunately when i change the language the position of the elements is changed and that I don't want it to happen. If anyone can help me please?

Also, Is there any way to make the elements Suitable even if the android device changed? In other words: this Layout runs on the emulator with the perfect size but when i launch the application on a Hardware device the positions are getting lower and i cant reach some of them( in this case i mean the button)

This is the Layout file:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="أهلا بك بقائمة المقترحات"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/suggestiontitle"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:text="عنوان المقترح"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_gravity="right"

            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">



        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="نص المقترح"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
            android:lines="10"
            android:minLines="6"    android:gravity="top|left"
            android:maxLines="10"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/suggestioncontent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/suggestioncontactinfo"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="معلومات التواصل"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>



    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/sendsuggestion"
        android:text="إرسال المقترح"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />





</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all read [THIS](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) carefully. Then consider wrapping your parent LinearLayout with ScrollView. It makes your layout scrollable and your bottom view will be reachable.

For the position change, you can use RelativeLayout, This happens because your language in Example supports RTL(RightToLeft).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a layout that doesn't change depending on the display size, it has to specified relative to the display. You can use a `PercentRelativeLayout` for that and specify sizes in percent.

This requires the percent support library http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#percent

Answer (score 0):

Try to use RelativeLayout and wrap it inside a ScrollView then if the layout goes out of the screen you can scroll it to see the rest of the view.

```
<ScrollView>
<RelativeLayout>
     <Child Layouts>
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody, I Used the Relative layout and it solves the problem.
this is the code after modifying it:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
       android:id="@+id/main_text"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="أهلا بك بقائمة المقترحات"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />




    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="عنوان المقترح"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/main_text"
       android:id="@+id/suggestion_title"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"

        />


    <EditText
        android:layout_below="@id/main_text"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/suggestion_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/suggestiontitle"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/suggestion_text"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/suggestion_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="نص المقترح"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/suggestion_text"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/main_text"
            android:lines="6"
            android:minLines="6"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:maxLines="10"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/suggestioncontent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contact_view"
            android:layout_marginTop="220dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/suggestion_text"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="معلومات التواصل"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/suggestioncontent"
        android:id="@+id/suggestioncontactinfo"
       android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/contact_view"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/sendsuggestion"
        android:text="إرسال المقترح"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/contact_view"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```